# How to re-enable buttons from Mainform to another form?

Tags: c#, forms, button

How do I re-enable a button from `Form1` to `Form2`.

The button is currently in `Form1` but I need it to re-enable in `Form2`.

Please see below my code :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;


    public object Form1 { get; private set; }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Label_XButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

I did add the "public form 1" still it doesn't allow me to do what i want it to do.

Comment: How do i do that i mean can you provide a sample. I am curently a begineer in programming. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a recipe:

1) change this line

```
public object Form1 { get; private set; }
```

to be of type `Form1`

```
public Form1 internalForm1 { get; private set; }
```

2) make a second constructor that takes a `Form1` as parameter:

```
public Form2(Form1 f1) : this()
{
    internalForm1 = f1;
}
```

3) pass the current instance of `Form1` into the constructor of `Form2` when you create it in `Form1`

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this)
```

4) make a method in `Form1` that does the changes

```
public void ChangeButtonStatus()
{
    this.button1.Enabled = !this.button1.Enabled;
}
```

4) and call this method in `Form2`:

```
private void Label_XButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    internalForm1.ChangeButtonStatus(); 
}
```

this will flip the button

Comment: I tried your's but the Form1 keeps on getting a red line.

Comment: Hi Mong, Can you write that on a notepad or something? It won't work. I dunno if i'm just so dumb at C#. Sorry i'm nota programmer but i'm willing to learn though.

Comment: @Tramyer when you hoover with the mouse over the red line, what does it say?

Comment: @Tramyer as Nino already pointed out, you need to show the `Form2` also: `Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);` (<- here you are missing a `;`) and you need to do this afterwards: `f2.Show();`

Answer (score 1):

Your `Form2` doesn't "know" for an instance of `Form1`. In other words, it doesn't know it exists. Pass instance of `Form1` to `Form2` via property or constructor. This is second approach:

make sure you have property in `Form2`

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;

    //you already have property, that's good! :)
    public Form1 Form1 { get; private set; } 

    //rest of Form2 code...
```

change `Form2` constructor like this, to enable passing instance to `Form2`

```
public Form2(Form1 frm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //"save" instance in property
    this.Form1 = frm;
}
```

On Form1, when instatiating `Form2`, pass it reference to `Form1`, like this:

```
Form2 frmTwo = new Form2(this); //"this" is Form1, passed as constructor's param.
frmTwo.Show();
```

Later, when you need to access something, like that button, you can to it like this:

```
private void Label_XButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Form1.button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Bro i tried your's seems simple but it won't work. or maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: @Tramyer looks like you correctly implemented Mong's suggestion. You just missed `f2.Show();`

Comment: I guess you woul need to set the `Modifiers` property of the button to `Public` in the designer and cast the `object Form1` to a `Form1` so that the compiler does not complain that the type `object` does not have a definition for the property `button1` like this: `(Form1 as Form1).button1.Enabled = true;`

Comment: @MongZhu, yes, button have to be `public` but i don't think that he casting is necessary. Anyhow, adding `this`, should be enough to tell compiler it's property. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the compiler will complain without a cast. using `object` leads inevitable to a cast when you want to access specific members of a certain type. How should the compiler know that the type will be `Form1` at runtime?

Comment: @MongZhu, we have a misunderstanding here :) Or, to be precise, I was a bit confused. When anwering, I made property `Form1 FormOne {get;set;}` but then saw that OP already have Form1 property. What I missed is that the OP's property is of type `object`. So, I'm looking at your comment and I was: "why should I cast anything?", thinking of property that I made and then deleted... :)

Comment: yo, in this case this fits nicely. :) Indeed it is a confusing way of declaring properties using an `object` as type and a type name as variable name. ?*!$§... ;)